# Using heapsort and quicksort together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to use both heap sort and quick sort so that it switches to a heap sort implementation when the recursion depth exceeds the log base of 2 of the size of the original list.

My heap sort function:

```
import heapq

def heapSort(lst):
    """
    heapSort(List(Orderable)) -> List(Ordered)
        performs a heapsort on 'lst' returning a new sorted list
    Postcondition: the argument lst is not modified
    """
    heap = []
    for item in lst:
        heapq.heappush(heap, item)
    sortedlist = []
    while len(heap) > 0:
        sortedlist.append(heapq.heappop(heap))
    return sortedlist
```

My quick sort function:

```
def medianOf3(lst):
    """
    From a lst of unordered data, find and return the the median value from
    the first, middle and last values.
    """
    a,b,c = lst[0], lst[len(lst)//2], lst[-1]
    return min(min(max(a,b), max(b,c)), max(a,c))

def quickSort(lst):
    """
    quickSort: List(lst) -> List(result)
        Where the return 'result' is a totally ordered 'lst'.
        It uses the median-of-3 to select the pivot

    e.g.  quickSort([1,8,5,3,4]) == [1,3,4,5,8]
    """
    if lst == []:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = medianOf3(lst)
        less, same, more = partition(pivot, lst)
        return quickSort(less) + same + quickSort(more)

def partition( pivot, lst ):
   """
   partition: pivot (element in lst) * List(lst) -> 
        tuple(List(less), List(same, List(more))).  
   Where:
        List(Less) has values less than the pivot
        List(same) has pivot value/s, and
        List(more) has values greater than the pivot

   e.g. partition(5, [11,4,7,2,5,9,3]) == [4,2,3], [5], [11,7,9]
   """
   less, same, more = list(), list(), list()
   for val in lst:
       if val < pivot:
           less.append(val)
       elif val > pivot:
           more.append(val)
       else:
           same.append(val)
   return less, same, more
```

Now I'm trying to implement quipSort so that it switches between heap sort and quick sort:

```
def quipSortRec(lst, limit):
    """
    A non in-place, depth limited quickSort, using median-of-3 pivot.
    Once the limit drops to 0, it uses heapSort instead.
    """
    if limit <= 0:
        heapSort(lst)
    else:
        quickSort(lst)
        quipSortRec(lst, limit -1)

    return lst

def quipSort(lst):
    """
    The main routine called to do the sort.  It should call the
    recursive routine with the correct values in order to perform
    the sort
    """
    l = math.log2(len(lst))
    return quipSortRec(lst, l)
```

It is not sorting at all, and I'm somewhat lost as what's wrong with my quipSort. My heap sort and quick sort perform fine though.

Comment: Off-Course: Shouldn't Heap Sort + Quick Sort be "Heck Sort" or "Quap Sort"

Comment: Please be more specific than "its not working": what *should* it do and what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start `quipSortRec` fine, but the `else` should look like a copy of `quickSort` with the recursive calls now calling `quipSortRec`.